# unable to plot heatmap with angular-plotly.js

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly, plotly.js, angular15

Generating heatmap with plotjs-angular is not working. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-plotly.js)   "angular-plotly.js": "^5.2.2", "plotly.js-dist": "^2.27.0","plotly.js-dist-min": "^2.27.0", "angular: 15"

```
  data: any = [
    {
      z: [
        [1, null, 30, 50, 1],
        [20, 1, 60, 80, 30],
        [30, 60, 1, -10, 20],
      ],
      x: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
      y: ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'],
      type: 'heatmap',
    },
  ];

<plotly-plot [data]="data" [useResizeHandler]="true"> </plotly-plot>
```